# How to replace in php? With str

Tags: php

I would like to remove all back slashes from strings on my site. I do not wish to use strip_slashes(), because I want to keep forward slashes.

This is the code I am trying:

echo str_replace("\", "", "it\'s Tuesday!");
I want to find the backslash in any given string and remove it. But, this code is not working right.

Error:

syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING
What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Server side process or clent side process?

Comment: Ever heard of regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$string = '<a title="Link 01" href="http://www.mywebsite.com.br/?id=121451781">Link 01</a>';

$l = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$old_href = $l['href'];
$new_href = str_replace("1","*",$l['href']);

$new_string = str_replace($old_href,$new_href,$string);

print($new_string);
```

This will extract the href element from the tag, and run replace on it, and then replace the old href element with the new one. You could do this with a single regex, but you have to try and see what is more effective.

I like the method I posted, because regex is often a bitch to try to figure out later on.

Comment: do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
$text = "
<a title=\"Link 01\" href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com.br/?id=121451781\">Link 01</a>
<a title=\"Link 10\" href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com.br/?v=1345fg6712&v2=11gdg123\">Link 10</a>
";

preg_match_all('#[a-z0-9]+=(?<params>[0-9a-z]+)">#u', $text, $matches);
foreach ($matches['params'] as $oldParam) {
    $newParam = str_replace('1', '*',$oldParam);
    $text = str_replace($oldParam, $newParam, $text);
}

echo $text;
```

**Result:**

```
<a title="Link 01" href="http://www.mywebsite.com.br/?id=*2*45*78*">Link 01</a>
<a title="Link 10" href="http://www.mywebsite.com.br/?v=1345fg6712&v2=**gdg*23">Link 10</a>
```

Comment: Because you were talking about "?id=", if you want, that it works for ever params you should replace `preg_match_all('#id=(?<id>[0-9]+">)#u', $text, $matches);`  =>>> `preg_match_all('#[a-z]+=(?<id>[0-9]+">)#u', $text, $matches);`       It works now?

Comment: @JonatasSilva, You have deleted all your comments.
You can return your conclusion and return the label "accepted answer"

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a title='Link 01' href='http://www.mywebsite.com.br/?id=*2*45*78*'>Link 01</a></li>
<li><a title='Link 02' href='http://www.mywebsite.com.br/?id=*2*45****'>Link 02</a></li>
<li><a title='Link 03' href='http://www.mywebsite.com.br/?id=*23345*78*'>Link 03</a></li>
<li><a title='Link 01' href='http://www.mywebsite.com.br/?id=235*78'>Link 04</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>


<?php

$a = file_get_contents('test.php');
$newdoc= '';
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $a) as $line){

$start = strpos($line,"id=")+3;
$end = strpos($line,">Link")-1;
$len= $end-$start;
$line = str_replace(substr($line,$start,$len),str_replace("*", "*", substr($line,$start,$len)),$line);
$newdoc .= $line."\r\n";
}

file_put_contents('test.php',$newdoc);

?>
```

Run this code and it will change the current documents expressions as you need. Output ->

Before : http://prntscr.com/hcg4y4 After : http://prntscr.com/hcg52i

Rate the answer if this is what you needed.

Comment: This works for all the expressions starting with "id=" and ending with ">Link". You can run a loop of this code on the all the links and it will replace all of them to match your needs.

Comment: Done what you needed but I guess you already got the working code.

Comment: Sorry, I think I accidently edited and replaced his answer instead of mine -.-